# Responsive LESS/CSS line gradient background

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Because I find it challanging creating static image backgrounds, such as example below, that are responsive and covers different resolutions and heights/widths, I was thinking using CSS3 color gradients to reproduce the same background and make it streching dynamically.

I would appriciate any input on tools/tips&tricks/etc on how to recreate such background with CSS. I have looked at online tools for generating CSS rules, such as http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients, but these doesn't create sharp line between two colors such as in my example.

[image: Example background]

Comment: I have looked on different online tools for creating css rules based on different options, but none of them actually made me recreating same background as here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set 2 linear gradient on top of each others, first with `rgba()` color with opacity to a few % .(or `hsla()` )
and the second with 100% opacity. about like this :

```
background:
    linear-gradient(
    130deg ,
    rgba(171, 17, 51, 1) 30%,
      rgba(255, 51, 102, 0.75)  
    ),
    linear-gradient(
    200deg ,
    #AB1133 50%,
      #FF3366 50%
    )
    ;
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/pJIHl)** tune it to your needs

Comment: Are there any reasons for using hex and not rgba/hsla colors in second linear-gradient?

Comment: it did not need to be translucide :) it was to make the point clear actually

Comment: Thanks! And do you know how fast this rendering is by using css and browser? I think it is faster then downloading 76-400KB image files based on resolution.

Comment: no idea, but once image is in browser cache ... one of the 2 colors, could be the bg color.

Comment: How would you make this background strech based on browsers width and height. Right now you need static size of div. In my case I set the background directly to body without the div, but my question is still applicable I believe.

Comment: the gradient will expand on all area avalaible. try it in html or body background http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/IFHiD